# Java modbus rtu slave

Tags: java, rxtx, modbus

I'm trying to develop a modbus rtu slave app. I've tried to use: j2mod, jamod, modbus4j, jmodbus. Non of them is working as I wanted to. I've googled for some examples but there is a lack of modbus rtu slave.

Could you please provide any links/codes/suggestions ?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you can say why j2mod, jamod, modbus4j, and jmodbus don't do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

there aren't many pc/phone/tablet mobdus rtu slave java implementantion because the rtu protocol must obey to strict timing to respect the standard.
Usually pc/phone ecc.. acts as master because modbus is a protocol for industrial devices that have register input/ outputs things that are not present in most of these devices.

the only suggestion i can give is to try to implement it is not so hard i saw you tagged rxtx try to use 
https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/

and for the implementation of the protocol the modbus organization provides documentation on how to implement the protocol because is free

http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf